# Adding Data To Array And Displaying It Dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, gridview, datatable

I want to insert data dynamically from database on click of a button to array and bind it to grid view control. The code below works but it accepts data only once and after another selection at overrides the previously selected data.

Or if there is any other method to do this please help

```
 protected void ASPxButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    

            for (int i = 0; i < 10;i++)
            {
                string[,] arrMultiD = { { DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString(), DropDownList2.SelectedItem.ToString(), DropDownList3.SelectedItem.ToString() } };

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("Category", Type.GetType("System.String"));
                dt.Columns.Add("Product", Type.GetType("System.String"));
                dt.Columns.Add("Price", Type.GetType("System.String"));

                for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add();
                    dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["Category"] = arrMultiD[j, 0];
                    dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["Product"] = arrMultiD[j, 1];
                    dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["Price"] = arrMultiD[j, 2];
                }
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, your problem is that your array saves the same data again and again by clicking on the action button.

There is a solution with multidimensional arrays.

You can insert the first values on the position 0 with the name firstData (or any other name) in your multidimensional Array and make an iterator to jump to the next position of the array. (like a for-loop). Then you can address to each single data in the array like Category, Product or Price. Whatever...

This would be logical approach.

Answer (score 0):

I get you but the issue is for using a for loop we have to specify how much time it will run and in this case I don't have the track like how much products would be purchased at a time!
So can't use it 
But thanks though!
Whereas now storing it into a session